# A mathematical model to get a probability of finding players at a particular location on the map in the game PUBG

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I assume you are aware about the game PUBG (see the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayerUnknown%27s_Battlegrounds)), where 100 players are dropped on island, and last team/individual to survive wins.

I was thinking about a mathematical model/framework for determining the probability of finding players at a particular location on the map by considering all parameters: flight path, RP of top players, numbers of players, offline players, and the map itself.

I am just brainstorming something like this. Could any body help in mathematical brainstorming of this idea?

Comment: I've never played pubg mobile myself - but how could you possibly predict where people choose to jump out?

Comment: To get anything like that actually working well in the end, you would need actual data on where players land. I don't think that that is very easy to obtain. On the other hand, if you have such data from, say, 1000 games (more is better, of course), then that's a completely different story.

Comment: What are your thoughts and ideas so far? What kind of models have you looked at, and why won't they work?

Comment: I would suggest practicing more in order to have a higher chance of winning, but to each his own.

Comment: Well see, the jumping thing depends mainly on loot reach areas near flight path, type of players (which we get to know from there RP). Basically I wanna connect all possible parameters to find the probability of players presence at a particular location on map. I have thought of in game parameters like flight path, RP, map, loot reach areas near route, mode of game and external parameters like server, local time of server

Comment: But the problem am facing is am unable to relate parameters properly and sometimes feel like am missing some parameters. Can some body easy this out?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the question is really: why shouldn't the distribution of players in the play area be uniform?  That is, each possible location is as probable as any other when looking for players.

In the initial stage players choose where to jump out of a plane that flies over the island, and they parachute down, so there is a small amount of control over where they land.  The path of the plane usually covers the centre of the island, so players can jump out anywhere and aim to land (almost) anywhere, so it would be reasonable to treat the distribution as uniform over the island, or perhaps as uniform over all but the sides it is hardest to parachute to.

However, if the loot (weapons mostly) is in fixed locations, then regular players may have strategies on where to parachute down to to maximise their chances of getting a favoured item of loot.  In this scenario you get clumping as players compete for loot, which rapidly disperses as players kill one another with the loot they've claimed.  As they must kill everyone else (except team members in team play) they then move out hunting for their next victim -- with no knowledge of where they may be -- so they must move randomly.  So the initial non-uniform distribution will rapidly become uniform again.

In the next stage, the play area shrinks to a circle of specific radius.  Any player outside that circle takes damage and quickly dies, so the probability of finding a player outside that circle falls quickly to zero, and inside the circle -- well, there's a brief  period where the circle boundary has a high probability of having players, but as they disperse into the circle and kill each other, it smooths out again.  Subsequent rounds shrink the circle more and more in order to force players to find each other and reach a resolution.

So for modelling, this is essentially a uniform distribution except at the start of each stage where (briefly) there is a peak at the boundaries.  Overall, I'd suggest that for the inital phase the heat equation $\Delta u = u_t$ will give a reasonable model with an initial distribution $u_0$ that is where players land from the plane; for the later stages the heat equation with a boundary condition $u(x,y,0) = c$ on $\partial B(x_0,y_0,r) $ will work.  $u$ will be the density of players.  This fails to model the race to the new area when the play area shrinks though, but this can be handled by a term that 'attracts' -- when players see each other they tend to move towards each other in order to obtain a kill.  This will need an $f(x)$ or maybe $u_x \cdot f(x)$ term to model.

It's worth noting that a model is built to *answer a question* and at the moment you haven't really told us what the question you want to answer is, which makes it hard to refine the model.  The probably location of a player on the map at any time feels like data for answering a different question.